# Data Warehouse design(BigQuery), load into dimensional table independent of fact table

Tags: database, google-cloud-platform, data-warehouse

I want to design a data warehouse (Data MART) with one fact table and 2 dimensional tables, where the data mart takes some Slowly Changing Dimensions into consideration, with surrogate key. I'm wondering how I can model this so that data insertion to the dimensional tables can be made independent (inserted before fact table row exist) of the fact table. The data will be streamed from PubSub to BigQuery via Dataflow, thus some of the dimensional data might arrive earlier, needing to be inserted into the dimensional table before the fact data.

Comment: Leaving aside design, you might not need to worry about the order of loading, as BigQuery does not support 'referential integrity' at all.

Comment: but the surrogate key will a be sequential integer for the fact-/dimensional tables

Comment: Nothing to do with BigQuery. Who, how and when generates values for fields (does not matter how one classifies those fields) - is irrelevant for loading data to BigQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I don't completely understand your question. Dimensions are always (or rather, *almost* always) populated before fact tables are, since fact table records refer to dimensions (and not the other way around).

If you're worried about being able to destroy and rebuild your dimension table without having to also rebuild your fact table, then you'll need to use some sort of surrogate key pipeline to maintain your surrogate key to natural key relationships. But again, I'm not sure that this is what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery does not perform referential integrity check, which means it will not check whether parent row exists in dimension table while inserting child row into fact table and you don't need this in data analytics setup. You can keep appending records to both fact table and dimension tables independently in BigQuery.

Flatten / denormalise the table and keep dimensions in fact tables - repeated records are not going to be an issue in BigQuery - you can make use of [Clustering and Partitioning](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/clustered-tables)

[image: Clustered and Partitioned Tables]

Other option is, if you have dimensions in RDBMS system, upload dimension tables as files to Cloud Storage / rows to Cloud SQL and join them in Dataflow, in this case you can skip multiple sinks - you can write to a flatten schema into a BigQuery table sink.

Inserting order does not matter in BigQuery, you can reference event records based on pubsub message publishing time / source event time, etc.